# Mysql Import - You have a error in your Syntax - Workarround

Tags: mysql, import

i use a exporter for some mysql data. At first it will create the table and after that insert the data into it.

Example Code

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dbc_Item-data`;
CREATE TABLE `dbc_Item-data` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field97` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field98` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field99` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field100` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field101` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
)
```

The Result was a Mysql Syntax Error, - after some research i found that the `,` before the last line will stop him from importing. So because my exporter is done via c++ i can't change currently this (also i can't write c), so my question is: Is there any workarround in the serverconf for this? I rather would like not to change every .sql file via an editor.

Sincerly Yours from Germany
Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

Given that the output is programmatically generated, I assume that the syntax error is entirely regular.  In that case, you can almost certainly solve the problem by replacing the string `,\n)` with `)`, using a scripting solution of your choice (`sed`, perl, or whatever else butters your muffin).

Comment: Okay this is a good idea, even better as do this everytime by hand :) Thank you